# Nhibernate schema Export

Tags: nhibernate

I created a database in my SQL Server and I want to export the schema using Nhibernate in C#. I have two classes called `Customer` and `Address`.

**customer.cs:**

```
public class Customer
{
    public int ID {get; set;}

    public Address Address1 { get; set; }

    public Address Address2 { get; set; }
}
```

**Address.cs:**

```
public class Address
{
    public string City{get;set;}

    public string Postcode{get;set;}
}
```

And I have written `customer.hbm.xml`. In that I defined addresses as `Component`:

```
<component name="Address1" class="Address">
  <property name="City" />
  <property name="Postcode" />
</component>
```

How can I export the schema when my classes are like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `SchemaExport` class to export SQL schema.

```
new SchemaExport(cfg).create(false, true);
```

Comment: I used SchemExport for this to be done.But i am not getting the component (address) values as fields

Comment: then there is a problem with the mapping file. it could help if you have included your mapping file as well.